# How to write this query with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to write select query with between similar to this with active record?

```
SELECT * FROM test_tbl WHERE date BETWEEN '$start' and '$end' ORDER BY ID
```

Regards

Comment: Reading the docs (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) has all the information you'll need.

Comment: It really doesn't demian. Its confusing and `between` queries aren't mentioned at all in there (unless they've changed it since I tried to find out exactly the same thing about a week or so ago).

Comment: Plus why the downvotes? Its an extremely reasonable question.

Comment: @Demian: RTFM isn't considered a proper answer/comment to SO questions. Not only that, but the docs don't address `BETWEEN` as Kernal mentions in his answer.

Comment: special Thanks to Kemal Fadillah,  yeah i checked the docs and there wasn't anything about between thats why i thought to post here to find out how they doing this

Comment: @David: The documentation *does* address custom queries, which would have been sufficient for the problem (Kernal's answer is better of course). While RTFM isn't considered a "proper answer/comment", neither is a "write my code for me" question. Usually a backstory coupled with attempts (or at least some form of showing that you've done some work before asking) is on par with what a good question looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no built-in support for `BETWEEN`

You can do this instead

```
$this->db->where("date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
$this->db->get("test_tbl");
```

Or write a helper function that look like this

```
function where_between($field, $min, $max){
     $CI = get_instance();
     return $CI->db->where("`$field` BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max'");
}
```

Later on, you can use that function by calling it like `where_between('test_tbl', $start, $end)`